# PHP regex cannot get it working?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to make a regex to match a certain criteria and I cannot get it working how I want it to.

My current regex is

```
'/S(?:[0-9]){2}E(?:[0-9]){2}/i'
```

What I would like it to do is match the following criteria

An `S`

At least one digit `0-9`

An optional digit that can be `0-9`

An `E`

At least one digit `0-9`

An optional digit that can be `0-9`

I would also like it to match the double numbers over single ones if this is possible, I made up the regex by following tutorials on the internet but think I am missing something.

Thanks...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$reg = "#S\d{1,2}E\d{1,2}#";

$tests = array('S11E22', 'S1E2', 'S11E2', 'S1E22', 'S111E222', 'S111E', 'SE', 'S0E0');

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    echo "Testing $test... ";
    if (preg_match($reg, $test)) {
        echo "Match!";
    } else {
        echo "No Match";
    } 
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Testing S11E22... Match!
Testing S1E2... Match!
Testing S11E2... Match!
Testing S1E22... Match!
Testing S111E222... No Match
Testing S111E... No Match
Testing SE... No Match
Testing S0E0... Match!
```

Explanation:

```
 $reg = "#S\d{1,2}E\d{1,2}#";
          ^ ^  ^  ^ ^  ^
          | |  |  | |  |
    Match S |  |  | |  One or two times
  Match digit  |  | Match a digit
One or two times  Match the letter E
```

**EDIT**

Optionally you could have done this with something like

```
$reg = '#S\d\d?E\d\d?#';
```

Which is to say, S followed by digit, possibly followed by another digit `?`... so on.

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I was looking for. There doesn't seem to be many tutorials that are any good covering this subject. I am guessing without checking that the `\d{1,2}` means digits 1 or 2?

Comment: @sberry sorry that was my typing it should be `S` then `E`!

Comment: @sberry Thanks for the explanation. Will accept it when the timer runs outs I have to wait.

Comment: There's no look-ahead in the original regex. (?:) means "don't store the match, I don't care what it is."

Comment: @BerryLangerak: right you are.  It's 3am here, time for sleep.

Comment: @Griff http://www.regular-expressions.info/ has a lot of good infos on regular expression. Also I recommend Mastering Regular Expression by Jeffrey Friedl if you want a good book about this subject.

Comment: @Arkh Ye I was looking at books and I had a few in mind and Jeffrey Friedl's was one of them guess it is his book that I will buy thanks.

Comment: @sberry I like the first it is more readable I think, thanks again awesome help!